# What scriptural verse proves (or disproves) that water is as pure as the container in which it's stored?

Tags: identification-request

For the sake of some arguments, i need to know which among the following two propositions is true.

**Prop A:**
 The water is as pure as the container in which it is stored.

That is, the original purity of the water gets lost due to getting in touch with the container whose purity is questionable.

**Prop B:**
 The water's original and inherent purity stays intact irrespective of the container in which it is stored.

So, i am looking for some verses which prove either A or B to be true.

NOte- It is quite common to find such verses in the Smritis.

Comment: Do you have some reason to suspect that Hindu scripture discusses this particular subject?  In any case, if Hindu scripture does touch on this, I assume it would be in the context of some kind of metaphor, like "Just as water's purity remains intact, so too does the soul remain undefined." Or "Just as water is only as pure as its container, ..."

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Well, i think, we can find such verses in the- Smritis (The Dharmashastras). Probably seen such verses already. And no, i am not looking for-such metaphors as they are not useful for my current purpose.

Comment: Oh ok, you're just trying to find out how to ensure that water is pure?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think it can be "proven" that the water , irrespective of it's purity while it's in the pot, regains it's original purity as soon as it leaves the container. There are other well-known methods of purifying water using mudras, mantras or otherwise too. So, no, i am not concerned about the purity of water because it is so for all our practical purposes. I just want to know about it's purity status while it's still in the pot.

Comment: I think B would be true according to some another anologies. I didn't find container anology though.

Comment: can you provide just one example from scriptures so-that one can get idea how to interpret?

Comment: *It is quite common to find such verses in the Smritis* Would you mind sharing an example ? I disagree with Proposition B btw. I have read Yijing's account (who stayed for some time in India, and documented local practices) and in that usually the water for different purposes is kept in different containers. And the container which usually contains dirty water, is not to be used for drinking, and it gets dirty just by being in touch with a dirty container. By dirty water I mean, water that is used for washing faeces, etc.

Comment: Manusmṛti 5.126 with Medhātitihi's comm. also points out that pure water gets impure on contact with unclean things, by being affected by smell, colour and taste. Proposition B is completely incorrect, and not in line with Indic tradition, according to me. As for proposition A, that only seems partially true because dirty, contaminated water can be stored in a clean vessel. Being stored in a clean vessel won't turn the dirty water into pure. However, if the pure water is placed in a dirty container, it's purity would be lost, as already pointed.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would quote from a Bauddha śāstra [南海寄歸內法傳](https://bdkamerica.org/download/1873) i.e. preserved in Taishō canon, numbered T. 2125. In this śāstra, Yijing (7th-8th century CE), a Bauddha bhikṣu from China details practices relating to Mūlasarvāstivāda Vinaya and general daily life practices of bhikṣus in India (majorly), based on his experience in India. Although focus is on the practices of Bauddha bhikṣus, but most of the secular practices (such as latrine, chewing toothwood, etc.) mentioned in the śāstra, confirm with the practices of common people of that period, as pointed out by the author himself many times in the śāstra.

> Water is used differently for pure and impure purposes, and it's kept
> separately in two bottles. Earthenware or porcelain bottles are used
> for keeping water for pure purposes, and copper or iron ones, for
> impure purposes. The pure water is kept for drinking in the afternoon,
> while the impure water is needed for washing after going to the
> latrine. The pure water bottle must be held with clean hand and be
> stored in a clean place, and the bottle containing water for impure
> purposes should be grasped with an unclean hand and be put at some
> unclean place. Only the water contained in a clean bottle, or in some
> new and clean vessel, is fit for drinking in the afternoon, while the
> water contained in other vessels is called 'timely water', which can
> be drunk without fault at noontime or before noon, but it's faulty to
> drink it in the afternoon. The water in the toilet jair is unfit for
> putting into the mouth or to the lips. After going back to one's
> chamber, one should rinse the mouth with water from a clean jar
> (*after answering call of nature*). In case one has touched the toilet
> jar after having finished the affair (*of excretion*), one should
> again wash one's hands and rinse one's mouth; then one may touch other
> utensils.

Clearly, there were separate bottles/containers for śuddha & aśuddha water, depending on the purposes each were used for. The bottles which contained water for activities such as defecation, were not used drinking water, as the water would be aśuddha by contact with those kind of bottles. Furthermore, Manusmṛti ([5.127-128](https://archive.org/details/manusmriti-with-manvartha-muktavali-part-i-ed.-rakesh-shastri-vidya-nidhi-prakashan/page/n363/mode/2up?view=theater)) clarifies what are śuddha objects as well as the fact that even śuddha water may turn aśuddha in contact with aśuddha objects. -

> trīṇi devāḥ pavitrāṇi brāhmaṇānāmakalpayan /  
> adṛṣṭamadbhirnirṇiktaṃ yacca vācā praśasyate // 
> āpaḥ śuddhā bhūmigatā vaitṛṣṇyaṃ yāsu gorbhavet / 
> avyāptāścedamedhyena gandhavarṇarasānvitāḥ //

Since śuddha water may turn aśuddha in contact with an aśuddha vessel, thus proposition B is invalid. As for proposition A, it's discussed as follows-

> That is, the original purity of the water gets lost due to getting in
> touch with the container whose purity is questionable.

This statement is true, in line with what's stated earlier.

> The water is as pure as the container in which it is stored.

But this line isn't valid in all cases because aśuddhajala may be stored in a śuddha container too. The śuddhatā of water is not ascertained only by the container it's placed in. However, placing aśuddha water in a śuddha container wasn't clearly the norm in olden times, as per Yijing. In that case, proposition A would be valid, but it lacks universal validity.

Comment: Ah. Very interesting...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.